# CString to TCHAR

Tags: c++, cstring, tchar

Today after a long time I've seen this conversion:

```
void SomeFunction( LPCTSTR szText ) ...


CString str;
str.Format( "A Simple Sentence" );
SomeFunction( LPCTSTR( str ) );
```

It compiles OK. Any explanations about this conversion?

It seems mostly ok, because I don't need to use `GetBuffer` and release it later, nor create a `new` `LPTSTR` with the length of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is OK, since `CString` has conversion operator to `LPCTSTR`. [reference to operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk1z2hd9)

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awkwbzyc.aspx#_core_using_cstring_as_a_c.2d.style_null.2d.terminated_string)

**The C++ compiler automatically applies the conversion function defined
for the CString class that converts a CString to an LPCTSTR.**

So, you don't need use explicitly conversion to `LPCTSTR`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is OK. According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300569%28VS.60%29.aspx) you just need to make sure that you don't modify the string during the duration of the returned pointer, which your code is doing fine.

This is basically the `CString` equivalent of `std::string::c_str()`.

Usually though you don't need to explicitly use the cast as your code does. The only reason I can think you need to do that is if you're converting to yet another type, for example if `SomeFunction` is defined as

```
void SomeFunction(const std::basic_string<TCHAR>& str);
```

In that case there is no implicit conversion from `CString` to `std::basic_string<TCHAR>` so you need to use `LPCTSTR` as an in-between.